# Hibernate Mapping Files And Configuration File in Different Folder Locations

Tags: java, hibernate

Its been over a decade since I used Hibernate, so a lot of the things I have forgotten.

I am trying to setup Hibernate, with my configuration file and the hbm mapping files for tables in different folders.

So I did the code like so:

```
/**
 * Initialize the Hibernate Session Factory.
 */
private void init () {

    try {

        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            
            configuration.addDirectory(new File("/opt/webserver/datasources/hibernate-tables-cfg"));
            
            sessionFactory = configuration.configure(new File("/opt/webserver/datasources/hibernate-cfg/hibernate.cfg.xml")).buildSessionFactory();
        
        } else if (sessionFactory.isClosed()) {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        
        logger.logException("Unable to get Connection to the Database: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

And in the configuration file my mapping tag is set like:

```
<mapping resource = "deviceGrouping.hbm.xml"/>
```

But I keep getting the exception:

org.hibernate.boot.MappingNotFoundException: Mapping (RESOURCE) not found : deviceGrouping.hbm.xml : origin(deviceGrouping.hbm.xml)

I am assuming since I am adding the directory for the mapping files in the configuration, I dont have to provide any paths (relative or absolute) in the XML file.

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how you run your application, but these files must be accessible on the class path. Apart from that, I would recommend you use the annotation model.

Comment: The XMLs are placed in a external directory, where the files are copied to during deployment.

Comment: I will try to read up on the annotation model.